# invalid operands of types ‘int(const char*)’ and ‘const char [11]’ to binary ‘operator<<’ while trying to write backup program (C++)

Tags: c++, linux

Please before you awnser this more than likely obvious question keep in mind that I am a sort of pleb programmer still trying to learn C++... If there are any obvious mistakes go easy on me.

So I am attempting to program a program that will create a backup of whatever file/directory the operator would like, but I keep getting a odd error. I have tried to use + instead of << (I know rookie move but you never know). I have also tried setting a std::sting but got a similar error (I have tried almost anything, but of course not everything because I havent fixed it yet).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;
int main() 
{
        char name ;
        char named ;
        std::cout << "This program will create a backup of whatever directory you would like. Please enter what you would like the backup to be named: "
        std::cin >> name ;
        std::cout << "Now please enter what directory you wold like to be backed up (Example: /bin/bash): " ;
        std::cin >> named ;
        system << "tar -zcvf " << name << "tar.gz " << named ;
return 0 ;
}
```

And this is the error I keep receiving:

```
backup.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
backup.cpp:12:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘int(const char*)’ and ‘const char [11]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
  system << "tar -zcvf " << name << "tar.gz " << named ;
```

(I know I should add breaks but at this point I am way past over it {for now})

Thank you to all who awnsered.. Very simple mistake and fix but I find this the best way to learn.

Comment: [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is a *function*; not an IO stream.

Comment: Gotta say that would be an elegant way to call `system`. Eliminates messing around building up a string to make the call. Be useful for opening files, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your program.

- Missing `;` in one of the lines.
- You need to use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read strings.
- Your `name` and `named` variables should be [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) not characters.
- [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is a function that takes a command line string argument.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    string named;
    std::cout << "This program will create a backup of whatever directory you would like."
        "Please enter what you would like the backup to be named: ";
    std::getline(cin, name);
    std::cout << "Now please enter what directory you wold like to be backed up"
        " (Example: /bin/bash): ";
    std::getline(cin, named);
    std::system(("tar -zcvf " + name + "tar.gz " + named).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`system` is a function that takes a `const char*` parameter, not a stream that uses the `>>` and `<<` operators.

You can combine the strings together and call it like so:

```
system((((string("tar -zcvf ") += name) += "tar.gz ") += named).c_str());
```